# HTML5 Problems in Firefox 15

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am facing problems with Firefox for HTML5, the below code should work fine and does in Opera and Google Chrome, but fails on Firefox 15 (worked fine with Firefox 14)

http://jsfiddle.net/bV54P/2/

The line on mousemove event is drawn sometimes in Firefox and sometimes it displays blank, not really sure whats wrong!!

The display message ("done") is logged on the console tough

Anyone facing the same problem?

**UPDATE:** seemes a bug in Firefox, posted it here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787623

Comment: I think you should move it to `document.ready` instead of `window.onload`

Comment: You're attacking things at too low a level and trying to play games against best practices. Load your javascript later on.

Comment: Probably best to report it to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=Canvas:%202D

Comment: just reported at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787623

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is a bug in Firefox 15, the canvas context is drawn (as observed on window / iframe resize or on DOM changes) you should report it to: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/